# Why is "marriage effective contingent upon the approval of the Sages"?

Tags: talmud-gemara, kiddushin-eirusin, maseches-gitin, chazal, maseches-kesubos

In [*Gittin* 33a](https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.33a.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), [*Kesuvos* 3a](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.3a.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) we learn that *Rabbanan* have the power to uproot a *kiddushin* because:

> **כל דמקדש אדעתא דרבנן מקדש** ואפקעינהו רבנן לקידושין מיניה

> **When a man betroths a woman, he does so under the conditions laid down by the Rabbis**, and in this case the Rabbis annul his betrothal.

My question revolves on how to fully understand this principle:

1. Source for it? Is it *d'oraisa* or *d'rabanan*?
2. Why does this principle exist by *kiddushin*/ *geirushin* specifically?
3. What is the rationale for it existing? We don't extend this principle in other areas like "**when a person makes a sale, he does so under the conditions laid down by the Rabbis**"

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/95979/9682

Comment: A peculiar remark about kiddushe kesef, Because the rule of hefker Bet din hefker. This mains that the Bet din has a power to neutralize the monetary ownship. So the Money of kiddushin may be confiscated from the husband and there is no kiddushin.

Comment: I have no time to answer but see Rashi who comments two pshatim. The pshat he doesn't reject is following a reasoning. People act following the custome, that is teached by our rabanim. And the rabanim fixed many problems by anticipation.

Comment: @kouty Your first comment seems to be in line with the Gemara’s statement of “that’s fine by Kiddushei Kesef,” but what about Kiddushei Bi’ah? What right do Chazal have to make it Bi’as Zenus?

Comment: @kouty where can I find that *Rashi*? By *Gittin* 33a or somewhere else?

Comment: Gittin 33a. Of course. There is a easy and interesting to at the same place

Comment: @kouty will be sure to check out- thanks!

Comment: @Doniel yes, the Rashi explains 2 pshatim in עשו רבנן את בעילתו בעילת זנות

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Kiddushin Performed "according to the tradition of Moshe and Israel"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18471/why-is-kiddushin-performed-according-to-the-tradition-of-moshe-and-israel)

Comment: @user15464 the focus of these questions seems very different. That one is about phraseology, this one is about source/rationale

Answer (score 1):

When a man marries a woman he says הרי את מקודשת לי כדת משה וישראל, "You are married to me according to the law of Moses and Israel." In other words, he only wants the marriage to go into effect if it is consistent with the laws of the Torah (דת משה) and other rabbinic decrees (דת ישראל).

Comment: Are you suggesting everyone always uses kiddushin al tnai?

Comment: Doesn’t Tosafos imply that it’s the reverse?

Comment: @DoubleAA, yes everyone is mikadesh al tna (see my next comment)

Comment: @Alex, Tosfos explains that b/c bes din has control over everyones money, they can force us to be mikadesh al tnai.